# Issue installing Doctrine ORM Module on ZF2 RC2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to integrate the [`DoctrineORMModule`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule) module with [`ZF2 RC2`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/release-2.0.0rc2) but I'm having issues. My `./composer.json` is as follows and `php composer.phar update` is running fine:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/orm": ">2.2,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/dbal": ">2.2,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "dev-master#a59928a3a37e420193939f9799ece27fb39bb84e"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "DoctrineORMModule": "src/",
        "DoctrineORMModuleTest": "tests/"
    }
}
```

However one of the modules added to `./application/application.config.php` is causing problems:

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'DoctrineModule',    // WORKS FINE
    'DoctrineORMModule', // 'Module (DoctrineORMModule) could not be initialized.'
),
```

This is confirmed when I issue the `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module` command:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module
>   (DoctrineORMModule) could not be initialized.' in
>   ./vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:139

If I search my `vendor` directory for Doctrine namespaces I can find namespaces for `DoctrineModule` (`grep "namespace DoctrineModule" -R ./vendor` finds things)  but not `DoctrineORMModule` (`grep "namespace DoctrineORMModule" -R ./vendor` doesn't).

**What am I missing in order to integrate `DoctrineORMModule` with `ZF2 RC2`?**

Comment: As this already has an accepted answer, i will leave this here. For windows users i've blogged about some specific problems installing Doctrine 2 for ZF2 right here > http://samminds.com/2012/07/install-doctrine-2-for-zend-framework-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to require "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module"

The DoctrineModule contains a bunch of abstract classes to give the ORM/MongoDB and other databases the same API.

Read more about installation DoctrineORMModule here
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule

Comment: Yes, what a pity, I forgot to require the only module that is documented as being required in the documentation (https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule). I tried to downvote my question but couldn't :) Anyway, cheers!

Comment: Don't down vote your question thats just stupid, im sure someone else will make that mistake :-P i know i done simular stuff myself

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need add

`"doctrine/DoctrineORMModule": "dev-master"`

like this

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "dev-master#a59928a3a37e420193939f9799ece27fb39bb84e",
        "doctrine/DoctrineORMModule" : "dev-master"
    }
}
```

then run

> php composer.phar update

Comment: That's what I tried initially, but `"doctrine/DoctrineORMModule"` is outdated and has been replaced by `"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module"`.

Comment: The reason for it being outdated is that composer doesn't accept names with capital letters in any longer.